# What is the significance of reversing the polarity of the negative eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a full rank $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$ (coming from a set of physical measurements). I do an eigendecomposition of this matrix as

$$A = E V E^T$$

Most of the eigenvalues are positive, while a few are negative but with much smaller magnitude compared to the maximum eigenvalue. I want to convert this matrix into a positive definite one but with minimal damage, for the purpose of my experiments. So I naively invert the polarity of the negative eigenvalues and construct a PSD matrix

$$B = E |V| E'$$

Later, I realized there is a whole lot of [research and algorithms](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/the-nearest-correlation-matrix/) available to find the nearest PSD matrix to a given symmetric matrix and what I am doing is not the right way. So I got hold of a few of those algorithms (with code) and tried out. These algorithms give nearest PSD matrix $C$ to $A$ than $B$ in terms of $2$-norm and Frobenius norm. Surprising part is when I use them in my experiments, I get far better results with $B$ than any of those algorithms. My understanding is that those algorithms usually end up in a low rank matrix (semi definite) and they do $C+\lambda I$ to make it make it a PSD where we get to choose $\lambda$.

I am not able to understand fully why $B$ is giving good results than $C$ and what is the significance of $B$. I'd like to understand this as i want better solution than naively going for $B$ albeit it gives results.

Comment: Of course the answer depends on what you mean by "good results." What are you doing with these matrices?

Comment: typo : $B$ is SPD symmetric positive definite$ as implied. I have written PSD.

Comment: @RajeshD Can you please check this question and your view on it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188459/flooring-of-eigenvalues

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, the "true" matrix that you're measuring really is only positive semidefinite with a large kernel.  Since you're doing physical measurements, the chance of getting any number exactly is nil, so all the zero eigenvalues are coming out as either tiny positive or tiny negative numbers.

If you flip the negative eigenvalues to positive ones, you're generating a positive *definite* matrix which behaves somewhat similarly to the "true" positive-semidefinite matrix.  I don't know what you're doing with these subsequently, but you may be feeding them through code that only works properly for positive definite matrices or something.

Try this: instead of flipping the signs, replace them with randomly-generated positive numbers of roughly the same order of magnitude and see what happens.  If the results are basically identical to the sign-flipping, then the problems you're having with the PSD matrix are probably some kind of numerical shenanigans.  If the flipped-signs version is behaving noticeably better (whatever that means in this context), *then* there might be something really interesting going on.

**Alternatively**: How sure are you that the software you're using to find the nearest PSD matrix is working correctly?

Comment: No, I get matrix $M$ from measurements, then I row reduce echelon  and remove redudant rows and colums from $M$ to get $A$. $A$ is full rank.

Comment: Well, right, because if you *measure* the entries of a matrix, the measurement error will *always* result in a full-rank matrix, whether the "true" matrix being measured was full-rank or not.  (Assuming these are continuous measurements and not discrete ones.)

Comment: Please be patient with your assumptions as your going tangentially. Please try to understand what I am saying. I get $M$, I check in matlab that $M$ is not full rank, (with what ever numerical accuracy matlab gives, I dont want to get into). My experiments dont work well with not full rank matrices(this assumption I clarify later). Now I row reduce $M$ to find out redundant rows and remove those rows from $M$ (not from row reduced M), to get $A$. this is how I get $A$ directly from measurements but full rank (in terms of matlab accuracy).

Comment: Please dont tell me any measurement matrix will be full rank. I am over that argument, and thats not the problem here

Comment: Suppose that one of the eigenvalues is $10^{-10}$. By any reasonable measure, this is a "zero" eigenvalue, but Matlab will count it as nonzero when you ask for the rank, since numerical zero is around $10^{-16}$. Just try this command and see: rank([1,0; 0, 1e-10])

Comment: If you take a set of continuous measurements, and you perform more measurements (columns) than you have variables (rows), then the matrix $M$ you obtain will have full row-rank no matter what due to measurement error.  The procedure you're applying to $M$ to generate $A$ will not change the row-rank.  Presumably the "true" row rank of the data you're measuring is lower, as evidenced by the fact that you have a few very small eigenvalues.  (All the MATLAB row-rank function is doing is counting the number of singular values above a particular tolerance.)

Comment: My measurements always yield square symmetric matrices. Please dont go on making assumptions about my experiemnts to satisfy your theories, that does not help me.

Comment: @NickAlger : try this cond([1,0; 0, 1e-10])

ans =

   1.0000e+10 My matrices are not as dumb as your example. you are suggesting me to dump matlab?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Yes, of course, but what is the relevance of that?

Comment: If condition number is too high, then we can invalidate our calculations. this is a way to keep track of matlab errors.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury : The crux of your argument is that by going from $A$ to $B$, I am increasing the rank, but no. rank(A) = rank(B) as I verify. AlsoI am just changing polarity, so it does not affect the rank irrespective of numerical accuracy? right?

Comment: Look, this is really easy to see what is going on. Just make a log plot of the singular values of your matrix with the command plot(log(svd(M))), where M is the matrix. If there is a sharp jump where the singular values drop very very small all of a sudden, then most likely those small ones after the jump are supposed to be zero, but are not quite due to rounding errors, conditioning, etc etc.

Comment: @NickAlger : I am over that problem. What I do is  : [~,rcol] = rref(M,10^-3); A = M(rcol,rcol);

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: Good to read that you have considered such things. However, to me $10^{-3}$ seems a pretty ambitious (relative) error level for real-world measurements. The plot proposed by Nick Alger might show what tolerance level is actually adequate.

Comment: No, I claim that by going from "real world" to $M$ (by taking measurements) you are increasing the row rank.  $M$, $A$ and $B$ will all have the same row-rank no matter what data you're measuring.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury : I like your answer from  "Try this..." part. I will get back with those results.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury : I have carried out the experiment you have suggested, with three different scenarios, 1. replacing negative ones with a constant positive value (mean), 2. making negative values zero, 3. reversing polarity of negative ones. ...(contd.)

Comment: I find surprisingly, the one that works best is (2.) that is replacing with zeros, iit works better than (3). I am not doing any matrix operations directly on the resultant matrix in my firther calculations, so probably semidefiniteness is good enough for me. The othet algorithms (nearest ones) are modifying all the eigen values which is causing worsening of results. Thanks for the help/suggestion. Please give your comments.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188459/flooring-of-eigenvalues

Answer (score 2):

There can be no definite answer because it has been left unspecified what
*good results* are and what the origin of the undesired negative eigenvalues is.
Anyway, the following might have to do with it:

- Adding $\lambda I$ to $C$ also distorts the originally positive eigenvalues,
  whereas $B$ leaves those unchanged.
- $B$ is auto-adaptive: The errors in $B$ automatically grow and shrink with
  the absolute values of the negative eigenvalues. In particular,
  if there are no negative eigenvalues, $B$ remains identical to $A$.
  In contrast, when adding $\lambda I$, care must be taken to ensure that
  $\lambda$ is large enough in all cases, and this adds unnecessary deviation
  from $A$, particularly when negative eigenvalues happen to be much smaller
  in magnitude than $\lambda$.
- That said, your way of approximating $A$ with $B$ is not *robust*:
  If the diagonalization happens to find a zero eigenvalue, $B$ will still have
  that, and will not be positive definite, only positive semidefinite.
  It seems however that you have actively tried to prevent such cases.
  This gets us to the next point.
- You mentioned that you obtain $A$ by removing redundant rows/columns from a
  matrix $M$.
  To recognize redundant rows, the row reduction algorithm repeatedly gets
  to a point where it needs to find out whether some number is approximately
  zero. Matlab allows specification of tolerance values there. If you set the
  tolerance too low (e.g. smaller than typical experimental error margins),
  then too few rows will be removed, and you get the effect that Daniel
  McLaury has described: small eigenvalues with random signs in place of zero
  eigenvalues. Instead of processing such artefacts, better avoid them by
  using a larger tolerance for the row reduction.
- You might also want to consider using methods that robustly work with
  semidefinite matrices. This might save you from having to reduce $M$
  in the first place, so you get a much more straightforward analysis.
  SVD and pseudo-inverses come to mind. But I am only guessing here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188459/flooring-of-eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

Given an invertible symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, an eigendecomposition of $A$ is

$$A = Q \Lambda Q^T = \begin{bmatrix} Q_1 & Q_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_1 & O\\ O & \Lambda_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Q_1^T\\ Q_2^T\end{bmatrix}$$

where the columns of orthogonal matrix $Q$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ and the entries on the main diagonal of diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

We build a new matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ that has the same eigenvectors as $A$. However, the eigenvalues in the block $\Lambda_2$ have their signs changed, i.e.,

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} Q_1 & Q_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_1 & O\\ O & -\Lambda_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Q_1^T\\ Q_2^T\end{bmatrix}$$

We write

$$A = Q_1 \Lambda_1 Q_1^T + Q_2 \Lambda_2 Q_2^T$$

$$B = Q_1 \Lambda_1 Q_1^T - Q_2 \Lambda_2 Q_2^T$$

Hence,

$$B = A - 2 \, Q_2 \Lambda_2 Q_2^T = \underbrace{(I_n - 2 \, Q_2 \Lambda_2 Q_2^T A^{-1})}_{=:R} \, A = R A$$

We now study matrix $R$,

$$\begin{array}{rl} R &= I_n - 2 \, Q_2 \Lambda_2 Q_2^T A^{-1}\\\\ &= I_n - 2 \, Q_2 \Lambda_2 Q_2^T (Q_1 \Lambda_1^{-1} Q_1^T + Q_2 \Lambda_2^{-1} Q_2^T)\\\\ &= I_n - 2 \, Q_2 \Lambda_2 \underbrace{Q_2^T Q_1}_{= O} \Lambda_1^{-1} Q_1^T - 2 \, Q_2 \underbrace{\Lambda_2 Q_2^T Q_2 \Lambda_2^{-1}}_{= I} Q_2^T)\\ &= I_n - 2 \, Q_2 Q_2^T\end{array}$$

which looks very much like a **Householder reflection**. Note that $Q_2 Q_2^T$ is a projection matrix whose rank and trace are equal to the number of eigenvalues whose signs are changed. Since $R$ is symmetric, it has an eigendecomposition

$$\begin{array}{rl} R &= I_n - 2 \, Q_2 Q_2^T\\\ &= Q Q^T - 2 \, Q_2 Q_2^T\\ &= Q_1 Q_1^T - Q_2 Q_2^T\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} Q_1 & Q_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I & O\\ O & -I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Q_1^T\\ Q_2^T\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$$

Thus, $R$ is **involutory**

$$R^2 = I_n \implies R^{-1} = R$$

and, since it is symmetric, it is also **orthogonal**. Hence, Euclidean distances are preserved

$$\|R x\|_2 = \sqrt{x^T R^T R x} = \sqrt{x^T x} = \|x\|_2$$

The Frobenius norm is also preserved

$$\|R X\|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr} (X^T R^T R X)} = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr} (X^T X)} = \|X\|_F$$

The Frobenius norm of $R$ is

$$\|R\|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr} (R^T R)} = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr} (I_n)} = \sqrt{n}$$

The spectral norm of $R$ is $\|R\|_2 = 1$. The determinant of $R$ is

$$\det(R) = (-1)^{m}$$

where $m \leq n$ is the number of sign reversals.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188459/flooring-of-eigenvalues